# Ember.js - Rendering data into a parents view / template

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I have a situation where I want data from a nested child route to show in a parent route's template. The child sub route renders into the parents {{outlet}} but theres a header in the parent's template that needs data added from the child.  I've tried a bunch of hacks and I'm currently using jQuery to put the data there.  What's the ember way to pull this off?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of data?  Like a single value, or a completely different template?  There are plenty of ways.

Comment: Try setting a value to the parent conroller. this.set('parentController.header', 'New Title')